# Change position of containers in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm still learning bootstrap and I would like to know what should I use move things inside a bootstrap container.
My question is a little bit strange but maybe with images and code it will be easier to understand.

I want to create a form in that precise position like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYk9O.jpg) image but I don´t know how can to do it. I don't understand if I have to apply margins or padding neither if it is suppose to change/apply css in the row or in the container.

At this moment my website looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQO8S.jpg) and my code is this one:

```
 <div id="form">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-7">

                    <form class="form-group">
                        <label for="testEmail">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="testEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can you guys explain me how can I change my form position and how it is suppose to move things inside bootstrap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `offset` like what you did. But here I prefer to create to `Columns` of `divs` inside `row`. please review this one: (*see in full screen to check the layout*)

```css
form {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 15px;
}
#form {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hidden-xs col-lg-3">test1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-3">test2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">        
        <form class="form-group">
          <label for="testEmail">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="testEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-xs col-lg-2">test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me to understand my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap's `offset` class for positioning elements as you need. Here is the documentation for `offset`:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns

Comment: I think that's not what I really asked... and I think you didn´t check my code too